# Flutter SafeArea overlaps camera hole in Android simulator

Tags: flutter

I am using SafeArea and my expectation that it would squeeze everything down below "brows", cameras, status bars, and what not... Unfortunately, when I run my app in Android simulator (Pixel 6 Pro), the camera overlaps my safe area.

I don't have a real Android phone to confirm if the problem is real. Is it a simulator's artifact? If not, what should I do to give my SafeArea additional padding to account for the camera hole?